# Insert PDF into Postgres database with python and retrieve it

Tags: python, postgresql, pdf, fastapi

I have to store a small PDF file in a Postgres database (already have a table ready with a bytea column for the data), then be able to delete the file, and use the data in the database to restore the PDF as it was.

For context, I'm working with FastApi in Python3 so I can get the file as bytes, or as a whole file. So the main steps are:

1. Getting the file as bytes or a file via FastAPI
2. Inserting it into the Postgres DB
3. Retrieve the data in the DB
4. Make a new PDF file with the data.

How can I do that in a clean way?

The uploading function from FastAPI :

```
def import_data(file: UploadFile= File(...)):
# Put the whole data into a variable as bytes
pdfFile = file.file.read()

database.insertPdfInDb(pdfFile)

# Saving the file we just got to check if it's intact (it is)
file_name = file.filename.replace(" ", "-")
with open(file_name,'wb+') as f:
    f.write(pdfFile)
    f.close()

return {"filename": file.filename}
```

The function inserting the data into the Postgres DB :

```
def insertPdfInDb(pdfFile):
conn = connectToDb()
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute("INSERT INTO PDFSTORAGE(pdf, description) values (%s, 'Some description...')", (psycopg2.Binary(pdfFile),))
conn.commit()

print("PDF insertion in the database attempted.")

disconnectFromDb(conn)
return 0

# Saving the file we just got to check if it's intact (it is)
file_name = file.filename.replace(" ", "-")
with open(file_name,'wb+') as f:
    f.write(pdfFile)
    f.close()

return {"filename": file.filename}
```

The exporting part is just started and entirely try-and-error code.

Comment: You'll need to show some sample of the code you've written and are working with.

Comment: Which of these 4 steps are you having difficulty with currently?

Comment: I can get the file from FastAPI and get it as bytes. No problem with that.
Inserting it in the database is ok too, but maybe the problem comes from there.
Retrieving the data isn't good, and so nor is putting it in a new file.